# How to determine that I'm not getting location updates anymore

Tags: android, gps, google-api, listener, google-api-client

My app requests location updates from GoogleServices via `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi` every 3 seconds. It has a nice, small satellite icon that indicates whether GPS is working or not.

I implemented `ConnectionCallbacks`, `OnConnectionFailedListener`, `LocationListener` interfaces in order to change the icon appropriately:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0)
{
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this); // starts location updates
    SetConnectionStatus(false); // AKA change GPS status icon to "not connected"
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0)
{
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
    SetConnectionStatus(false);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0)
{
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
    SetConnectionStatus(false);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0)
{
    if (arg0 == null)
    {
        SetConnectionStatus(false);
        return;
    }

    SetConnectionStatus(true);
}
```

Now, this seems to work like a charm except for one situation. I turn on the GPS in my phone and start the app. The icon quickly changes from "not connected" to "connected" and I start getting updates every 3 seconds in LogCat. Then, I minimize the app and turn off the GPS. The icon still says "connected" despite the fact that I completely stopped getting new location updates (LogCat doesn't print them).

My question is, how do I detect that I stopped getting new data? Is there some kind of listener I should implement? I don't want to create a separate thread whose sole purpose is to check every 5 seconds whether I'm still getting updates or not.